# Basic definition of numerical analysis

Tags: numerical-methods

Can someone help me who can define numerical analysis that can easily understand by a student? 
I googled it and still it's hard for me to understand its meaning.

Answer (score 1):

https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/NAessay.pdf‎

This is the essay my numerical analysis professor always hands out at the start of the semester. It has a good explanation.

Comment: dalbrit Thank you sir.

Comment: You're welcome. In my opinion, it's probably not a thrilling read unless you are already a numerical analyst haha.